# Call a SOAP service in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, soap

I try to call temp converter service in SWIFT code but, i get same println in the console "NO":

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var is_SoapMessage = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns='http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/'><Celsius>0</Celsius></CelsiusToFahrenheit></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"



            var is_URL: String = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit"

            var lobj_Request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: is_URL)!)
            var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            var err: NSError?

        /*

            lobj_Request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            lobj_Request.HTTPBody = is_SoapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            lobj_Request.addValue("testest.it", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
            lobj_Request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            lobj_Request.addValue(String(count(is_SoapMessage)), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
            lobj_Request.addValue("http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")

*/
        var msgLength = String(count(is_SoapMessage))


        lobj_Request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        lobj_Request.addValue(msgLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        lobj_Request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        lobj_Request.HTTPBody = is_SoapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) // or false

            /*
            var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(lobj_Request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
                println("Response: \(response)")
                var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                println("Body: \(strData)")




                if error != nil
                {
                    println("Error: " + error.description)
                }
                else
                {
                    println("OKAY")
                }
            })

            task.resume()

*/

        var connection = NSURLConnection(request: lobj_Request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
        connection!.start()

        if (connection == true) {
            var mutableData : Void = NSMutableData.initialize()
            println("OKAY")
        }
        else
        {
            println("NO")
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

I don't see where is the error, I don't have lines with error. I try to understand why I can't get "Yes" message, someone could help me ?

Comment: ```if (connection == false) {``` would also output ```NO``` because connection is not a boolean (true or false). It is of type ```NSURLConnection```. What exactly do you want to check?

Comment: @abinop I just want to check if the call is good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

connection is not of type Bool, so you will always get falso with `connection == true`. It is just like asking if a banana is an apple. the obvious answer will always be "false"

To check if the connection object has been allocated you should check if it is not nil so the if should be `if connection != nil` this does not ensures you that "the call is good" like you said in your comment. It will just ensures that the connection object has been created with success, and you should check it BEFORE you call the start method on it. (And you don't really need to call the start method since you put true for the start immediately parameter)

```
if let connection = NSURLConnection(request: lobj_Request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true) {
    connection.start() //You don't need it because you set the startImmediately param to true
    //whatever you want to do the connection
}
```

Comment: Okay I understand, so I can check if my connection object has been created with success but I can't know if it's good ?

Comment: I want to consume a personnal web-service (with login functions) and I use w3school web service to train me in swift, now I created the object connection but I don't really know if it's work, if I can consume the convert functions

Comment: you still didn't told me what means for you "it's good". If you meant "that request succede you have to implement the delegate methods of the NSURLConnection, and read the response.

Comment: There are a lot of tutorial on this online just googling NSURLConnection swift example. This is just the first one i found: http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/06/20/making-http-requests-in-swift/

Comment: I want  to consume the SOAP service too

Comment: You get the data implementing the delegate methods of NSURLConnectionDelegate. with them you will understand if everything is fin or the error, and you can try to understand what's wrong. How to parse the data you get is a totally different problem that has a lot of documentation and tutorials. Just google NSXMLParser swift tutorial for example.

Comment: Well I'm gonna do some search about, sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: The english was fine. Mark the topic as answered if it helped so anyone can benefit of the solution.

Comment: I will do if I find the solution, because if y get an error on function call of a soap web service I will edit my question

Comment: Stack overflow doesn't work like this. but do whatever you want. You should open a different question so that answers will not be unrelated.

Comment: Ok I will open an another question